# How to go switch back to the MainActivity from a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a MainActivity, which starts fragments, in according to a specific button pressed. When I'm under a fragment and I press the back button, the application will be closed. My idea is, when the back button is pressed, I will show the MainActivity, with all the button. I write these lines of code in the MainActivity:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
       recreate();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Is it a good solution ? It works quite well, the only things is that between the transaction of fragment layout and the activity layout, there is a black screen for less then half second. is there any way to fix it ?

Comment: can you share the code for recreate()? Also, you can use fragment manager to replace fragments

Comment: The recreate(); method is available by Android, it is not mine. Can I also pass from a fragment to another fragment directly ?

Comment: Ahh..I just read about the recreate method..It causes this Activity to be recreated with a new instance. so, it's not recommended way, Yes, you can communicate with other fragments by use of interfaces.Check out this documentation. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: So what do you suggest for my situation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are adding the fragment, add it to backStack. The back press will automatically revert the fragment and shows your main activity.

Eg:

```
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(..............);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: Why you placed null ? What does it mean ?

Comment: Its just a tag. In order to remember what fragment current being placed, you can use that tag. Its not mandatory, if you dont want a tag or dont want to remember what is the current fragment, you can use null. In complex systems, one fragment holder will be used for showing many fragments. So in such cases, it is hard to find which fragment is currently in and to know that we use those tags.

Comment: Bu does the method addToBackStack(null) save also the Activity, which commit/execute the fragment ?

Comment: I don't understand what you meant by saving. The activity will remain the same while the fragments will be added/removed/replaced which for which you need to remember which fragment is currently in

Comment: I mean this: I have the layout of the Activity, with the button, which pressed, a new fragment will appear. I want that, once the back button is pressed, the layout of the Activity will appear. I hope now it will be more clear :)

Comment: Its a bit clear, it should work. But am bit perplexed that you're using the entire layout of activity to be replaced as fragment. Is it so?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81155/discussion-between-harish-sridharan-and-i-love-coding).